# graphing a circle in the complex plane?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

The ellipse seemed rather simple: [Defining the equation of an ellipse in the complex plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126121/defining-the-equation-of-an-ellipse-in-the-complex-plane)

But Wolfram won't graph it with equal axes. [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs{%28x%2Bi*y%29}%2Babs{%28x%2Bi*y%29}%3D1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs%7B%28x%2Bi*y%29%7D%2Babs%7B%28x%2Bi*y%29%7D%3D1)

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. If I follow the title, the equation of a circle of centre $a+ib$ and radius $r$ is given by $|z-(a+ib)|=r$. Is it what you want ?

Comment: @Surb graphing the circle = harder than typing the equation in Wolfram.

Comment: What do you mean by graphing ? you want to draw it ?

Comment: @Surb I was trying to get wolfram alpha to graph it without success.

Comment: @Surb yes I mean draw = graph.

Comment: is there a question ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be better trying:

$$z=e^{i\theta}$$ or $$z=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$

These are derived from Euler's famous formula:

$$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$

They more naturally plot the unit circle in the complex plane.

Comment: Wolfram doesn't graph you equations. Though image searching them yeilds the desired circles.

Comment: It graphs the sine and cos functions separately and not plotted in the real plane!